# Google API throwing error after multiple run

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to call Google MAP API in my python code but failing.

My Code:-

```
import requests
import urllib.parse


address = input("Address: ")
key = "****************************"
main_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

api_call = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':address})+"&"+urllib.parse.urlencode({'key':key})


json_data = requests.get(api_call).json()

print("API Status: ",json_data['status'])
if json_data['status'] == "OK":

    print("\nAirport Name: ", json_data['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'])
    print("Locality: ", json_data['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'])
    print("Country: ", json_data['results'][0]['address_components'][4]['long_name'])
    print("\nFormatted address: ", json_data['results'][0]['formatted_address'])
else:
    print("API not working.")
```

I ran the code with Adress input 'maa', when I directly open the API link in the browser I am getting json datas but python code throwing below message

> Address: maa
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=maa&key=***********************
>
> API Status:  REQUEST_DENIED
>
> API not working.

Attached the API response from the browser
[image: API data return from browser]

Comment: There is limit of API call in google API, are you passing map API key in your each call?

Comment: @Kishan yes I am passing key each run but this is the output from the first run itself.